# How to process reply with InboundEndpoints in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2-esb

Just starting out with InboundEndpoints in version 4.9.0 of the WSO2 ESB.

I would like to create an inbound endpoint that polls for incoming files, forwards this to a service and saves the service reply to a file.

I have read the available docs and examples and this is what I came up with.

```
<inboundEndpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
                 name="testinbound"
                 sequence="TestIn"
                 onError="fault"
                 protocol="file"
                 suspend="false">
   <parameters>
      <parameter name="interval">1000</parameter>
      <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/xml</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.LockReleaseSameNode">false</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.AutoLockRelease">false</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">DELETE</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.CreateFolder">true</parameter>
      <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">//C:/Test/ST/in</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">//C:/Test/ST/failure</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.DistributedLock">true</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*\.xml</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.Streaming">true</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">//C:/Test/ST/original</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.Locking">disable</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileSortAscending">true</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileSortAttribute">NONE</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.Build">false</parameter>
   </parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
```

where the "TestIn" sequence looks like:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
          name="TestIn"
          onError="fault"
          statistics="enable">
   <in>
      <send>
         <endpoint key="conf:/stock_quote_config/stock_quote_endpoint_reg"/>
      </send>
   </in>
</sequence>
```

Now I have a couple of questions about the behavior of this code, and how to achieve my goal.

1. How to get my hands on the reply of the service? I have tried to add an `<out>` mediator in the `TestIn` sequence. I got the following:

   `OutMediator Current message is a request - skipping child mediators`
2. I also tried the `transport.vfs.ReplyFileURI` and `transport.vfs.ReplyFileName` parameters. 
   Strangely, these options are not available via the UI. I could specify them in the configuration source file, without any effect.

(These parameters are described in the documentation of the 4.9.0 version. See 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/VFS+Transport )

3. So how to save the reply? And how to redirect the reply?
   I see that after the `TestIn` sequence the `<main>` sequence is executed by the ESB on the response path -- this is what I would like to redefine.
4. I get an error that the file could not be moved from the "in" to the "original" folder. (In fact, after execution the file is moved.)

> [2015-11-20 13:36:55,145] ERROR - FilePollingConsumer Error moving
>   file : file:///c:/Test/ST/in/test.xml to //C:/Test/ST/original
>       org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not delete "file:///c:/Test/ST/in/test.xml".
>               at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.deleteSelf(AbstractFileObject.java:849)
>               at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.moveTo(AbstractFileObject.java:1139)
>               at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.file.FilePollingConsumer.moveOrDeleteAfterProcessing(FilePollingConsumer.java:842)
>               at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.file.FilePollingConsumer.directoryHandler(FilePollingConsumer.java:568)
>               at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.file.FilePollingConsumer.poll(FilePollingConsumer.java:214)
>               at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.file.FilePollingConsumer.execute(FilePollingConsumer.java:134)
>               at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.file.FileTask.taskExecute(FileTask.java:45)
>               at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.common.InboundTask.execute(InboundTask.java:44)
>               at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.ntask.NTaskAdapter.execute(NTaskAdapter.java:90)
>               at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:67)
>               at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
>               at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>       Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not delete "c:\Test\ST\in\test.xml".
>               at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.local.LocalFile.doDelete(LocalFile.java:127)
>               at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.deleteSelf(AbstractFileObject.java:838)
>               ... 16 more

Answer (score 0):

You can use Call mediator instead of send  mediator. When the response is received, the mediation flow resumes from the next mediator in the sequence. So you can redirect or process the incoming response.